# Is There a Way to Convert System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary of Datatable To Type System.Byte[]?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, sql-types

I have a dynamic picturebox in C# and it get the picture from a column of datatable 
the datatable structure is:

```
public DataTable Pictures = new DataTable();
Pictures.Columns.Add("id", typeof(bool));
Pictures.Columns.Add("filebytes", typeof(SqlBinary));
```

and i have a array of byte to show pictures in picturebox:

```
byte[] ImageBinary;
```

and the following code is for showing image:

```
                        PictureBox a = new PictureBox();      
                        a.Location = new Point(100, 90);
                        a.Size = new Size(25, 25);
                        a.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        groupBox3.Controls.Add(a);
                        MemoryStream ms = null;
                        Image img = null;
                        Tools b = new Tools();
                        ImageBinary = b.CreateImageBinary(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                        ms = new MemoryStream(ImageBinary);
                        Pictures.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, ImageBinary });
                        img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                        a.Image = img;
                        ms.Close();
```

> it get image from a Openfiledialog

i want to assign a value to picturebox from datatable my problem is when i change the code like this:

```
 ImageBinary = (byte[])Pictures.Rows[sm][1]; //sm is a variable to specific a row of datatable
```

it get me error like:

> Unable to cast object of type 'system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary' to type
>   'system.byte[]'

i am confused help me please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DqlBinary.Explicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary.op_explicit?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public static explicit operator byte[] (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary x);
```

My suggestion would be to add the `using System.Data.SqlTypes;` import in the beginning of your `.cs` file where the explicit operator is declared.

Check the documentation for the dlls that include it in case the compiler can't find the namespace.

Comment: can you say it clear? what should i use ? above code?

Comment: Add the using I mentioned and cast as you do now.

Comment: I added that .but the problem is when i use explicit operator it tells me user defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosyng type